# Color of NoRowsMessage cannot be set using report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am building some SSRS 2008 report using MSS Report Builder 3.0.

I set `NoRowsMessage` in Tablix's properties with a value from a DataSet `=First(Fields!tab_aucun_resultat.Value, "TRADUCTIONS")`.

I modify this message's `color`, in order to manage it from an another application, using a parameter.
[image: Expression for the <code>color</code>]

The color of the NoRowsMessage isn't changed when report is executed. It is still the default color.

I have the same problem when it comes from a DataSet.

Is it a bug or did I make it bad ?

Comment: What is the Data_Font_Color.Value that you are trying to pass in?

Comment: It is a parameter of the report (string). It could be `Orange` or `#8019F`...

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the Color value? Does that changes the color?

Comment: I wonder if the values you're passing in are incorrect. I set up a test and it worked fine for `Red`, `Blue`, `Orange`, `#00FF00`. Maybe it's a typo, but `#8019F` isn't valid, and in the BIDS preview gives a runtime warning and displays black text.